# MapStruct / mapping interface field / java

Tags: java, spring, interface, mapping, mapstruct

**Hello! I've been trying to make a mapping of BookDTO.java to Book.java using MapStruct but I've encountered the issue**

**Here's my DTOs:**

BookDTO.java:

```
@Data
@Document
public class BookDTO {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private BookSpecificationsDTO specifications;

}
```

BookSpecificationsDTO interface:

```
public interface BookSpecificationsDTO {
    BookSpecificationsTypeDTO type = null;

    default BookSpecificationsTypeDTO getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

BookSpecificationsTypeDTO:

```
public enum BookSpecificationsTypeDTO{

    CLASSIC,
    PHANTASY
}
```

ClassicBookSpecificationDTO:

```
@Data
public class ClassicBookSpecificationDTO implements BookSpecificationsDTO {
    private BookSpecificationsTypeDTO type = BookSpecificationsTypeDTO.CLASSIC;
    private String genre;
    private int length;
}
```

PhantasyBookSpecificationDTO:

```
@Data
    public class PhantasyBookSpecificationDTO implements BookSpecificationsDTO {
        private BookSpecificationsTypeDTO type = BookSpecificationsTypeDTO.PHANTASY;
        private String genre;
   }
```

**And here are my models, which in my case are identical to the DTO's:**

Book.java:

```
@Data
@Document
public class Book {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private BookSpecifications specifications;

}
```

BookSpecifications interface:

```
public interface BookSpecifications {
    BookSpecificationsType type = null;

    default BookSpecificationsType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

BookSpecificationsType:

```
public enum BookSpecificationsType{

    CLASSIC,
    PHANTASY
}
```

ClassicBookSpecification:

```
@Data
public class ClassicBookSpecification implements BookSpecifications {
    private BookSpecificationsType type = BookSpecificationsType.CLASSIC;
    private String genre;
    private int length;
}
```

PhantasyBookSpecification:

```
@Data
    public class PhantasyBookSpecification implements BookSpecifications {
        private BookSpecificationsType type = BookSpecificationsType.PHANTASY;
        private String genre;
   }
```

**I wanted to map my BookDTO.java to my Book.java model. Here's the mapper class:**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
public interface BookMapper {
        
    @Mapping(target = "id", expression = "java(java.util.UUID.randomUUID())")
    Book toBook(BookDTO bookDTO);

}
```

**Here's the errors I get:**

```
java: The return type BookSpecificationsDTO is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.
```

**and**

```
java: Can't map property "BookSpecificationsDTO specifications" to "BookSpecifications specifications". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "BookSpecifications map(BookSpecificationsDTO value)".
```

**So, my question is can I get this work somehow? Is it possible to map BookDTO.java to Book.java in  such case if one of the fields is an interface? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: You do know that fields in interfaces are implicitly `static`, do you?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write a mixin, which isn't supported in Java. (Groovy traits can do this, but if you want to do that in Java, you need an abstract base class.)

Answer (score 0):

When the target type is an interface or an abstract class there has to be one of the following:

- A method annotated with `@ObjectFactory` that would create the target object
- A mapping method with `@BeanMapping(resultType = XXX.class)` that would define the result type

---

In your case the problem is slightly more complex due to the fact that your interfaces have no setters. Therefore, you need something like [Support for Type-Refinement mapping (or Downcast Mapping)](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131), this is currently a feature request and not yet possible out-of-the-box